# Error: Undefined object! while parsing JSON using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json

This should be simple but I cannot seem to get this to work correctly.

Given a JSON string that looks like this:

```
     {
    "?xml":

         {
        "@version":"1.0",
        "@encoding":"ISO-8859-1"
         },
    "results":
    {

         "title":"AOL Movies - Closest Theater and Showtimes",
        // etc,
        "theater":
        {
            "theaterId":"10650",
            "id":"10650",
            // etc
        },
        "movie":
            [
                {
                "studios":"Warner Bros.",
                "movieId":"61683"
                        }
                 ]
}
```

I continually get undefined objects when trying to get to any value, for example:
data.movie, or data.results.title.

Everything "looks" ok in the output.

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: 'handler.ashx',
        data: 'zip=' + postalCodes.join(','),
        success: function (payload) {
            var data = that.objectifyJSON(payload); // this returns typeof = object

            that.constructMoviesArray(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error.responseText);
        }
    });

this.constructMoviesArray = function (data) {
    var key, movie, theater = null;

    var movies = {};

    movies.items = {};

    movies.length = 0;
    alert(data[0].movie); // FAIL - there's clearly an array but nothing displays
```

I hope this is enough information; I am not experienced with JSON and jQuery so I'm struggling to figure out why I can't seem to resolve this.

Comment: just wondering, have you tried data.results.movie[0]?

Comment: I sure did. Got a object error as well indicating result is not an object.

Comment: what is objectifyJSON?  you are asking about a parsing problem but excluded your code that does the parsing

Comment: @RobertLevy It's a few lines that do the following:
if (typeof (json) == "object") {
         return json;
     }
     else {
         return jQuery.parseJSON(json);
     }

This condition returns typeof(json) == "object" so it returns the json variable value without modification. I displayed the payload contents in my first entry.

Comment: That's fine that it returns an object but have you inspected that this object is actually what you expect?

Comment: @RobertLevy I'd like to split the answer with you and Matthew. So it turns out the core of the issue was the HttpHandler; I was serializing each element in a List<string> and then serializing the entire List<string> object, when instead I should have only serialized the entire List<string>. When I closely inspected the output it occurred to me finally that I had a bunch of strings and not objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the json `dataType`. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

The server response is probably still a string even though you set the `contentType`.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: 'handler.ashx',
    data: 'zip=' + postalCodes.join(','),
    dataType: 'json', // <--- UPDATE ME
    success: function (payload) {
        var data = that.objectifyJSON(payload); // this returns typeof = object

        that.constructMoviesArray(data);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert(error.responseText);
    }
});
```

If that doesn't help, try adding a `console.log` or a breakpoint to the success callback. You'll be able to take a closer look at what kind of data you are working with in `payload`.

```
success: function (payload) {
    console.log(payload);
},
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you - I did review the payload and what I posted was exactly what it looked like. @Farax, I did try that and the debugger threw another undefined object error. Everything I've read says this should work. Any other suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: @Teknophyl What does the console.log show for `payload`?

Comment: The entire JSON output is very large and wouldnt fit here. I truncated it for the purposes of the example above. It returns a 5 element array , and each element is a JSON object. It's on the first object I'm trying to get these properties.

Comment: What does `console.log(JSON.parse(payload));` produce? And `console.log(payload[0].?xml)`

Answer (score 0):

Try Like

```
var geocodingAPI = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true";

$.getJSON(geocodingAPI, function (json) {

    // Set the variables from the results array
    var address = json.results[0].formatted_address;
    console.log('Address : ', address);

    var latitude = json.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
    console.log('Latitude : ', latitude);

    var longitude = json.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
    console.log('Longitude : ', longitude);

    // Set the table td text
    $('#address').text(address);
    $('#latitude').text(latitude);
    $('#longitude').text(longitude);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/5pjha/822/)